# Whois and server host information privacy

Tags: domain-registrar, nameserver, whois, private-registration

I have a domain that is privately registered, so if you run a whois, you will just the domain registrars name.  And below are two questions:

1. Since i am using private registration, is there a way somebody can find out i own it?
2. Will the nameserver information still show even if its privately registered?

Answer (score 3):

Some domains allow you to hide your details, such as .co.uk address, .com address hiding your credentials isnt. However, in a number of webhosting places, they actually own the domain on your behalf, as a result your details are then  hidden because only the webhoster knows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about others but for GoDaddy private registration I think I read somewhere that you can find out the details of private registrant. (I don't have the link though)